# Display Image in WordPress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm trying to display an image via WordPress REST API using `register_rest_route`. But the display is still string even though I added it under  tag. I am trying to figure out how to display an image like https://quickchart.io/qr?text=abc123 in API.

I am using QRCODE by Kazuhiko Arase - https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator
[image]

This is what I've tried.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route( 'api/v1', '/product/', array(
      'methods' => 'GET',
      'callback' => 'ea_get_product_data',
    ) );
} );

function ea_get_product_data( $data ) {
    $identifier = $data->get_param( 'identifier' );
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/qr-code/qrcode.php';
    $response = new WP_REST_Response;
    $response->set_headers( ['Content-Type'   => "image/gif"] );
    $qr = new QRCode();

    $qr = QRCode::getMinimumQRCode($identifier, QR_ERROR_CORRECT_LEVEL_L);
    $img = $qr->createImage(8, 8, $fg = 0x000000, $bg = 0xFFFFFF, $bgtrans = false);
    ob_start();
    imagegif($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
    $img = ob_get_clean();  
    $response->set_data( '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode($img).'" />' );
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your output is escaped. Maybe you can try to create a proper response. Try to add something like this at the end of your callback:

```php
$output['title']             = 'Your image name.';
$output['title']['rendered'] = $base64;
$response                    = rest_ensure_response( $output );

return $response // <= Should be an instance of WP_REST_Response, or WP_Error if something went wrong.
```

Comment: I've tried also this approach but still it doesn't work. But I've updated my script above and added WP_REST_Response. It is now converted as an Image but the result is can't find the image using base64

Comment: I see you are using Postman, maybe there is some configuration required to display an image?
Did you tried to display it in your browser? Like in a rendered HTML page?

Comment: That’s right I’m using postman and Yes I tried it using html in the browser and it is working. I think the issue was my setup in API or maybe I missed something..